# What does "なのかもっと" mean here?

Tags: translation

> ただでさえ子供みたいなのかもっとそう見えてくるから

I asked this once in some other site. Basically, this is a dialogue from 2 old ladies complaining about their husbands. Here's the full dialogue.

> Lady 1: ろくな稼ぎでもないくせにメシだお風呂だウルセーんですよ
>
> Lady 2: 紗月ちゃんは子供がいないだけマシかもね...
>
> Lady 2: ただでさえ子供みたいなのかもっとそう見えてくるから

I think I understand what the 2nd and 1st line mean. (Though I'm not sure if the 2nd line implies that Lady 2 has children.)

It's just the 3rd line that's giving me trouble. I've learned how to use たださえ and みたい but the "なのかもっと" in the middle is confusing me.

Is "のか" separate from the "な" or is just "なのか"? What does it do in the sentence?

Comment: This should be 子供みたいなの**が**, not か. This が is the subject marker. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: I see. "Even if something is like a kid, it looks more than that"? What does 子供みたい describe here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know you said that only the third line was a problem for you, but let me handle the whole dialogue that you quoted.

> Lady 1: ろくな稼ぎでもないくせにメシだお風呂だウルセーんですよ
>   Lady 1: My husband can't even bring in much money and order me just as if as I was his maid, he's unbearable. (pretty liberal translation)

> Lady 2: 紗月{さつき}ちゃんは子供がいないだけマシかもね...
>   Lady 2: That's probably a good thing that you (=紗月{さつき}ちゃん) don't have kids ...

> Lady 2: ただでさえ子供みたいなの**が**もっとそう見えてくるから
>   Lady 2: 'cause having kids would make you feel even more so.

- 子供みたいな = things like kids
- そう = ウルセー in sentence 1
- もっとそう見えてくる = would looks like even more unbearable.

ただでさえ is here as an intensifier, it's used to underline that the situation without the problem is already quite dire, so when another problem stack up, the situation is so dire you can't help.

Here, the dire situation is: 紗月ちゃん coping with her husband alone. Now, let's imagine she had kids…

Answer (score 4):

> 紗月ちゃんは子供がいないだけマシかもね...
>
> Your situation may be better than mine because you don't have a child...

> ただでさえ子供みたいなの**が**もっとそう見えてくるから
>
> (I'm saying this) Because (if you had a child,) the one who is already like a child would look more so.
>
> → Your childish husband will start to look even more childish (if you have a real child, because, unlike our husbands, real children are earnest and hardworking beings), you know!

- [ただでさえ](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=tadadesae) is a set phrase which literally means "even in its plain state". It's used to compare something with something more extreme. Here "already" should be a good translation.
- 子どもみたいなの is "the one who is like a child" and it refers to their lazy husbands. Here, の is a special noun meaning "one(s)", "the thing", etc. The following が is just a subject marker.
- そう refers to "childish".